# Entropy derivation from Multiplicity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, entropy, probabilistic-method

```
Multiplicity(W)= N!/(n1!*n2!....ni!)

Entropy = 1/N * ln W = 1/N*ln N! - 1/N*sigma_for_all_i(ln ni!)
```

As N->infinity,

By Stirlings approximation

```
ln N! ~= N*ln N - N and ni/N fraction is fixed.
```

By using the above facts how can we conclude that for N->infinity

```
entropy = sigma_for_all_i(pi*ln pi) where pi = lim ni/N as N->infinity
```

Comment: Looks easy: Stirlings approximation for $N!$ and for $n_i!$ and then $\sum n_i=N$. Then $n_i/N \to p_i.$

Comment: @Mr.Spot Nice one. It took some time for me to realize that Stirlings approximation can be used for ni!. But when N->infi,   ni->infi too. From this fact its easy to derive the result.

Comment: @Mr.Spot  How are you able to use subscripts and sigma sign?

Comment: [use this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)